# Android - List of images in row

Tags: android, image, list

how I can create a list of images, that are in a row(line)?

I have a layout, where I want to show result of (football) match that can be 3 types - win (green icon with "V" inside), lose (red icon with "P" inside) and draw (orange icon with "R" inside). But I need to show undefined amount of matches, so it should look like this:
[Image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juvY8.png). Also, I need that this image should be clickable (to start new activity with details about match).

So, how I can create it? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look into RecyclerView and using GridLayoutManager

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use "Gridview" rather than a "ListView". I guess "Gridview" will be a most appropriate option for your requirements.

Here is an example:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html